# `Parameter 'Property cannot be empty: Region, StartUrl'` When Trying To `dotnet lambda deploy-function`

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

I am trying to onboard to AWS as my team will be responsible for building features on it relatively soon. Since I expect we'll be building and deploying an AWS Lambda, that seemed like the natural starting point. First I set up my AWS CLI by using `aws configure` with a profile name of "my-profile" and then aws sso login using the values from my AWS account page with an SSO session name of "my-sso". Then I created a new ASP.NET Core API using the `LambdaASP.NETCoreMinimalAPI` template and configured the `aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json` as follows:

```
{
  "Information": [
    "This file provides default values for the deployment wizard inside Visual Studio and the AWS Lambda commands added to the .NET Core CLI.",
    "To learn more about the Lambda commands with the .NET Core CLI execute the following command at the command line in the project root directory.",
    "dotnet lambda help",
    "All the command line options for the Lambda command can be specified in this file."
  ],
  "profile": "AdministratorAccess",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "configuration": "Release",
  "function-memory-size": 128,
  "function-timeout": 30,
  "function-runtime": "x86_64",
  "function-url-enable": true,
  "function-handler": "SimpleLambdaApi"
}
```

Then, from a PowerShell terminal, I called `dotnet lambda deploy-function SimpleLambdaApi --profile "my-profile"` and I get back the following error:

```
Created publish archive (E:\src\repos\AWSLambdaExperiments\SimpleLambdaFunction\src\SimpleLambdaApi\bin\Release\net6.0\SimpleLambdaApi.zip).
Error retrieving configuration for function SimpleLambdaApi: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'Property cannot be empty: Region, StartUrl')
```

I also tried `aws sso login --profile "my-profile"` though I'm not clear on the difference between that and `aws sso login --sso-session "my-sso"`. What am I doing wrong here? I'm trying to follow various tutorials I've seen in AWS docs and other places but I'm missing something fundamental.